# What's the difference between apt-get dist-upgrade and do-release-upgrade?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, upgrade

Will apt-get dist-upgrade do the exact same thing as running do-release-upgrade?

I'm currently running Ubuntu Server 11.04.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`apt-get dist-upgrade` will not carry out a release update, unless you modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

This command updates all installed packages and their dependency changes.  If you combine running this command with appropriate changes to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, you can upgrade your version of Ubuntu.

`do-release-upgrade` will carry out a release update.

So for example, if you want to move from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10, you have 2 options:

1. Change each occurence of the word "natty" in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to "oneiric" and run the command `apt-get dist-upgrade`
2. Run the `do-release-upgrade` command.

Comment: do-release-upgrade has some other cool features, like "--sandbox", which remounts your filesystems with aufs so that the upgrade can be rolled back!